# Run scheduled task from VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, scheduler, taskscheduler

How to run scheduled task inside .vbs script?

It's not about how to schedule .vbs script inside Task Scheduler.

But I have a task that I want to run by running this one .vbs script.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-scheduler-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to shell out to the [`schtasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc725744(v%3dws.11)) commandline utility.

```
taskname = "something"
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
rc = sh.Run("schtasks /run /tn """ & taskname & """")
```

You could also use the [Task Scheduler scripting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-scheduler-objects), but that would require more code.

```
taskname = "something"

Set sched = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
sched.Connect()

Set root = sched.GetFolder("\")
Set task = root.GetTask(taskname)

task.Run Null
```